# Show the categories the current post has

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, php, loop

I have a custom post type; posts of this type can have either one or two categories associated with them. I need to display the names of the categories that are associated with each of these custom posts within the loop. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have added the `category` taxonomy to your Custom Post Type, you can simply call `the_category()`.

Alternately, if you're using a custom taxonomy, you can echo the results of `get_the_terms( $id, $taxonomy )`.